# Propensity Score Matching by using Nearest Neighborhood Method with weights in R

Tags: r

I am performing Propensity Score Matching in R by using one of my variable as weighting Factor, i.e., Weight. I want to do Matching using nearest neighbor method. The sample of my data is:
      `dput(dat2)`:
       
        `structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7),
        Weight = c(2.4740626, 2.4740626, 2.4740626, 2.4740626, 1.9548149, 1.9548149),
        Age = c("35-44", "<15-24", "25-34", "35-44", ">45", "25-34"),
        Treatment = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
        Outcome = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)), 
        row.names = c(NA, -6L),
        class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))`

I am using tableone package to create a pre-matching table. My code is here:

```
`model1<-lm(formula = dat2$Outcome ~ dat2$Treatment + dat2$Age, 
       data = dat2,weights = Weights)
model1
Effect<- model1$coeff[2]
Effect

pscores.model<-glm(dat2$Treatment ~ dat2$Age,
                family = binomial("logit"), data = dat2, weights = dat2$Weights)
summary(pscores.model)

Propensity_scores<-pscores.model
dat2$Pscores_1<-pscores.model$fitted.values
require(tableone)
xvars<-c("Age")
table1<-svyCreateTableOne(vars = xvars, strata = "Treatment", data = dat2, test = FALSE)
print(table1,smd = TRUE)

require(MatchIt)
match2 <- matchit(pscores.model, method="nearest", radio=1,data=dat2)
match2
ATE_ATT_2.1<-ATE(Y = dat2$Outcome,
           Ti = dat$Treatment,
           X = dat$Age,
           ATT = TRUE
)
ATE_ATT_2.1
ATE_ATT_2.2<-ATE(Y = dat$Outcome,
           Ti = dat$Treatment,
           X = dat$Age,
           ATT = FALSE
)
ATE_ATT_2.2
match2.data <- match.data(match2)
#Create the tableone for nearest matching
table_match2 <- CreateTableOne(vars = xvars,
                           strata = "Treatment",
                           data = match2.data,test = FALSE)
print(table_match2, smd = TRUE)`
```

But when I am running this code, it is giving results without weighting factor and it is not taking weights as an argument inside CreateTableOne function. 
Please help me regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this code.

First, to use the `svyCreateTableOne` function, you need to supply it with a `svydesign` object in the `data` argument, which you have not done. You need to use the `survey` package and supply it with weights. In your case it looks like you are using this function on unweighted data anyway, so you probably shouldn't be using it.

Second, in your call to `matchit()`, you have the argument `radio=1`. `radio` is not an appropriate argument to `matchit()`. You probably meant `ratio`. Fortunately, this probably won't affect anything.

I don't know why you have the `ATE()` code in there. It is irrelevant to the problem.

I don't know what weights you are intending to appear in your final table, but you didn't supply any weights for it to use. In your first table, you give it unmatched, unweighted data. In the second table, you give it matched, unweighted data. What weights are you trying to supply? If you want to give it weighted data, you need to supply those weights using `svyCreateTableOne` and a `svydesign` object that has the weights.